# Add these blogs to the list of sites page

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, blog-overflow

[Sci-Fi](https://thesffblog.com/) and [Worldbuilding](https://medium.com/universe-factory) maintain their own blog, but they aren't listed on the [page of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic).

Server Fault has one listed (last updated 2017), but not these other two.

Please can they be added?

Comment: Server Fault's blog is part of the same domain, is it still hosted by SE? If so I can see why that's included but the community funded and ran ones aren't.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that's a good point

Comment: Server fault appears to be the only one with a blog link. It certainly would be nice to get the community blogs listed, but they may not want them as they aren't officially part of the site.